# xml many to many join using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, many-to-many

I could be wrong in writing proper code or asking question, but I'm looking for assistance in the following.

I have an xml file with many to many relationship as follows:

```
<ShowRoom>
  <Cars>
    <Car id="1" number="001" name="MyCar" >
      <Parts>
        <Part id="1" />
        <Part id="2" />
      </Parts>
    </Car>
    <Car id="2" number="002" name="YourCar" >
      <Parts>
        <Part id="2" />
        <Part id="3" />
        <Part id="4" />
      </Parts>
    </Car>
  </Cars>
  <Parts>
    <Part id="1" name="Tyre" active="true"/>
    <Part id="2" name="Window" active="true"/>
  </Parts>
</ShowRoom>
```

Corresponding to that object is follow

```
public class Car
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _number;
    public string Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set { _number = value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private List<Parts> _listParts;
    public List<Parts> ListParts
    {
        get { return _listParts; }
        set { _listParts = value; }
    }
}
```

What I am trying is to read xml and join between car and parts, so I will get car object with their all parts details

```
  IEnumerable<XElement> xCar = xdoc.Element("ShowRoom").Element("Cars").Elements("Car");
                IEnumerable<XElement> xPart = xdoc.Element("ShowRoom").Element("Parts").Elements("Part");
                IEnumerable<Car> car = xCar.Join(
                    xPart,
                    c => c.Element("Parts").Element("Part").Attribute("id").Value,
                    p => p.Attribute("id").Value,
                    (c, p) =>
                    new Cars
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(c.Attribute("id").Value),
                        Number = (string)c.Attribute("number").Value,
                        Name = (string)c.Attribute("name").Value,

                        ListParts =  
                        { 
                                new Parts
                                    {
                                        Id = int.Parse(p.Attribute("id").Value),
                                        Name = (string)p.Attribute("name").Value,
                                        Active = bool.Parse(p.Attribute("active").Value)
                                    }
                        }
                    });
```

The problem here is that I dont know how to get all parts against car like in above code which is obviously wrong

```
                        ListParts =  
                        { 
                                new Parts
                                    {
                                        Id = int.Parse(p.Attribute("id").Value),
                                        Name = (string)p.Attribute("name").Value,
                                        Active = bool.Parse(p.Attribute("active").Value)
                                    }
```

So how to get it done using the same above code, or if there is other good way to do so, do share with me.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a point here, why set private properties when your creating public methods that allow the caller to both Get & set the those proprties anyway, you should just leave them as public if your intention is to allow the caller to perform get & set.

Comment: @JonSkeet apologies if i've confused things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest building a dictionary of parts, *then* building up the list of cars:

```
Dictionary<int, Part> partsById = doc.Root
    .Element("Parts")
    .Elements("Part")
    .Select(p => new Parts
            {
                Id = (int) p.Attribute("id"),
                Name = (string) p.Attribute("name"),
                Active = (bool) p.Attribute("active")
            })
    .ToDictionary(part => part.Id);
```

Note that I've renamed `Parts` to `Part`, as each object only represents a single part - and I've removed all the parsing, using the explicit conversions on `XAttribute`.

Then when you build your cars list, you can use:

```
...
ListParts = c.Element("Parts")
             .Elements("Part")
             .Select(p => partsById[(int) p.Attribute("Id")])
             .ToList();
```

You should also look into automatically implemented properties, which would reduce your `Car` class to just a few lines of code:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Parts> ListParts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, its marvelous. I can't vote up as it required some reputation. Thanks Derek for your feedback.

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies if i've caused confusion, I'm suggesting your class should look like how John has his set here, that is all.

Comment: @Derek: It's worth understanding that this is *absolutely equivalent* to the poster's original code. It's still got private fields and public properties. Nothing's changed on that front - it's just a simpler source representation.